# Installation of Vollkorn font

Tags: fonts, mac

I'm trying to install Vollkorn font from `.otf` files on OSX with the help of `autoinst`.

On a separate folder I run the command `autoinst -target=~/Library/texmf/ Vollkorn-*.otf` which should install the different versions of Vollkorn (http://vollkorn-typeface.com/).

Without luck so far this ends with such messages for all font variants:

- `otftotfm: encoding ‘fontools_ot1’ not found`
- `otftotfm: encoding ‘fontools_t1’ not found`
- `otftotfm: encoding ‘fontools_ly1’ not found`

Finally, `[WARNING] 'otftotfm' returned non-zero; something's wrong! at /usr/texbin/autoinst line 643.`so that the operation has failed.

Note that LCDF-typetools are installed.

Comment: Is there any chance you can make the switch from pdfLaTeX to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? Given that the Vollkorn font comes in OpenType format, using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with this font would be trivially easy: You'd load the `fontspec` package and issue the command `\setmainfont{Vollkorn}`.

Comment: Don't install fonts for TeX into your home `texmf` tree unless you have no other options (e.g. you don't have admin rights on the machine). It is better to install into the local `texmf` tree (`/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`) so that you don't have problems with updates.

Comment: Those encoding files are part of TeX Live so if you have the full version of MacTeX installed, you should have them. Is your TeX installation up to date? What does `kpsewhich fontools_ot1.enc` give?

Comment: It gives `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/fontools/fontools_ot1.enc`

Comment: `autoinst` has an option to save rather than executing the commands needed to install fonts. Try using that option to see exactly how it is trying to use `otftotfm` as it is difficult to know what might be going wrong when the process is hidden by a wrapper.

Comment: I am running into the same problem, even if I do not try to install the fonts in my home `texmf` tree. Any updates on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not totally solve the problem (I'm not sure I succeeded in getting `autoinst` to work properly), but at least I no longer get the error messages.

The problem seems to be that `otftoftm` cannot find the encoding files that are in the `fontools` directory (`fontools_ot1.enc`, etc.). If you copy those files to wherever you are running `autoinst` from, `otftoftm` should be able to find them.